# How to reference Dymola experiment start time and stop time as variables?

Tags: modelica, dymola

For simple test models, I commonly a syntax similar to:

```
// Assuming the start time is 0 and stop time is 1
x = xMin + (xMax - xMin) * time;
y = f(x);
```

To be correct no matter the simulation setup, I would like to use:

```
x = xMin + (xMax - xMin) * (time - startTime) / (stopTime - startTime);
y = f(x);
```

However, I am unsure how I can reference the values defined in the Simulation Setup / General form.

I have tried simply referencing StartTime, startTime, starttime, timestart, timeStart, etc. with no success.

I understand that it is possible to set StartTime and StopTime using an annotation, but those values are only set the first time a model is opened and so may not truly reflect a simulation's start time and stop time.

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not possible to access the stop-time of a simulation inside Dymola to use in the model, but you can get the start-time as follows:

```
  parameter Real startTime(fixed=false);
initial equation
  startTime=time;
```

Note that if you use Simulation>Continue>Continue the `startTime` will not be updated, but continue with its original value.

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect, but you could provide the information from outside:

Add the start- and stop-time as parameters to your model

```
parameter Modelica.SIunits.Time stopTime = 0;
parameter Modelica.SIunits.Time startTime = 1;
```

and use a function to perform the simulations

```
function sim
  input Modelica.SIunits.Time startTime = 1;
  input Modelica.SIunits.Time stopTime = 2;
algorithm 
  DymolaCommands.SimulatorAPI.simulateExtendedModel(
    "model-name", startTime, stopTime, 
    initialNames={"startTime", "stopTime"}, 
    initialValues={startTime, stopTime});
end sim;
```